# Как менять скриптом переменные заданные в препроцессоре SASS

Tags: css, sass

Верстка сайта сделана в препроцессоре `sass`.

Основные цвета сайта записанные в переменные, типа:

`$primary = #000`

Сейчас веду работу над скриптом который будет менять основной цвет сайта.

Вопрос как менять эту переменную?

Была мысль что в основной `css` передаются эти переменные, но нет, классические `css` переменные и в `sass` разные вещи.

Если какое то решение или придется переписать на классические?

Comment: Препроцессоры переводят код в чистый CSS. И скорее всего переменные вставляются как обычные значение (а не CSS переменные).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы планируете менять цвета в `runtime`, тогда как `sass` работает на этапе компиляции, приводя все к обычному CSS.

Вам следует использовать несколько переменных для нужных цветов:

```
$color-primary: red;
$color-secondary: blue;
```

Определить их для отдельных классов:

```
.primary {
   color: %color-primary;
}

.secondary {
   color: %color-secondary;
}
```

После чего Вы сможете управлять сменой цвета через добавление / удаление классов:

```
const changeColor = () => {
   const p = document.querySelector("p")
   p.classList.add("secondary")
}
```